# android.app.RemoteServiceException when sending a push notification

Tags: android, push-notification

I am getting following exception on some of the devices mostly android 4.3/4.4 (Samsung/Moto G). However it is working fine when i am debugging it on my device as well as emulator. 
Following is the exception

android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.xxxxx: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification

Here is my code

```
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,TipOfWeekActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(CureMeConstants.MESSAGE, msg);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.store_icon)
    .setContentTitle("Tip of the week")
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentText(Html.fromHtml(msg , null, new ListTagHandler()));

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);

    mBuilder.setVibrate(null);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Here is how my layout looks like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TipOfWeekActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollbars="none|vertical"
        android:layout_above="@id/ad"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:contentDescription="@id/title"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/tip_of_week" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:linksClickable="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnHome"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:onClick="goBackHome"
                android:text="@string/goBackHome"
                android:textColor="#0000FF" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone suggest me what can be the possible issue? Is this specific to Android version? Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

On further investigation, i found following exception on the emulator

couldn't inflate view for notification

"paragraph span must start at paragraph boundary"

However in my code, i have already handled a paragraph, ul and li tags.

```
private void handleListTag(Editable output) {
        if (m_parents.lastElement().equals("ul")) {
            output.append("\n");
            String[] split = output.toString().split("\n");

            int lastIndex = split.length - 1;
            int start = output.length() - split[lastIndex].length() - 1;
            output.setSpan(new BulletSpan(15 * m_parents.size()), start,
                    output.length(), 0);
        } else if (m_parents.lastElement().equals("ol")) {
            m_index++;

            output.append("\n");
            String[] split = output.toString().split("\n");

            int lastIndex = split.length - 1;
            int start = output.length() - split[lastIndex].length() - 1;
            output.insert(start, m_index + ". ");
            output.setSpan(
            new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(15 * m_parents.size()),
                    start, output.length(), 0);
        }

    }
```

This code also works perfectly fine on Android device with version 4.1.2. Does someone know about exception in handling list tags in android 4.3/4.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that above functionality doesn't throw exception on all devices.

On debugging the code, i found out following things.

RemoteViews were not getting expanded when the message to be displayed in Notification Window contains tags like **ul li** etc. When TextView within NotificationBuilder encounters such tags, it is not able to expand the view and throws exception even though tags are handled properly using TagHandler. Simple solution is to remove such tags from the Notification Windows display.